# Janusgraph using Gremlin query in .net core 3.0

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, .net-core-3.0, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

We currently use gremlin.net library in a net core 3.0 application to connect to Janusgraph db.

We need to execute below query in janusgraph
`g.V('12345').outE('myedge').has('datetime',lt(1581922847)).order().by('datetime', incr).limit(100).valueMap().as('time').inV().as('user').select('time','user')`

The query runs fine as long as we dont have `inV()` part. If we have `inV()`, we are facing below error,
`ScriptEvaluationError: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Edge`

1. Is there a way to run/rewrite this query without splitting it into two? Am new to janusgraph and this works fine in Cosmos db.
2. As per [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239255/gremlin-net-system-invalidoperationexception-deserializer-for-janusgraphrela), I understand there is a custom deserialization involved in janusgraph. I tried that, but still doesn't help me. Can someone, post a working code that adds a custom deserialization in .net core 3.0.

To have a simpler example, the query `g.V(1).as('v').outE().limit(1).as('e').select('v','e')` works directly in gremlin console but not with `gremlin.net` library(groovy-string) for janusgraph. We have tried both GRYO and GraphSON Serializer settings in server. We are in a position to use groovy-string as this is an existing application.

Comment: I believe there is a typo in the last part of the query: `.select('time,user')` should be `.select('time','user')`. Could you try this? Would it give the same output?

Comment: @LuisBosquez Apologies. Edited the question, the problem still exists in our application. The query works fine in Azure cosmos db, gremlin console but does n't help in janusgraph connected from gremlin.net 3.4.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The query runs fine as long as we dont have inV() part. If we have inV(), we are facing below error, ScriptEvaluationError

You can't have `inV()` because it follows `valueMap()`. `inV()` is meant to traverse from an `Edge` object to its incoming `Vertex`, but `valueMap()` converts the `Edge` to a `Map` and you thus get the error of: "java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Edge"

I think you just want:

```
g.V('12345').
  outE('myedge').has('datetime',lt(1581922847)).
  order().by('datetime', incr).
  limit(100).
  project('time','user').
    by(valueMap()).
    by(inV())
```

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen. It means a lot to me!!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [JanusGraph.Net nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JanusGraph.Net/)! since there are JanusGraph-specific types that Gremlin.Net can't serialize.